# JPA Native Query set null parameter

Tags: java, jpa

Here is my code part:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("insert into table_name (value_one, value_two, value_three) values (?,?,?)");
q.setParameter(1, value1);
q.setParameter(2, value2);
q.setParameter(3, value3);
q.executeUpdate();
```

`value3` sometimes can be null (Date class object). And if it is null the following exception is thrown:

```
  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "value_three" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 88
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:189)
    ... 11 more
```

How is it possible to get this code working and to persist null value into database?

Comment: what is your database? can you execute the query directly?

Comment: Did you check in the database whether the column actually allows `NULL`? Also, please check whether the field in entity is annotated with `@Column(nullable=true)`?

Comment: **PostgreSQL 9.2.** Yes, I can do it in such a way directly: `insert into table_name (value_one, value_two, value_three) values ('test', 'test', NULL);`

Comment: Also, can you try it with `setTimestamp()` instead of `setParameter()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `javax.persistence.Query` doesn't have such a method. May be it is possible to cast it to `org.hibernate.Query`, that has such a method?

Comment: @AlexKartishev How have you done the mapping from `Date` to postgresql `Timestamp` .

Comment: No mapping. `value3` is `java.util.Date` object and if it is not null it is persisted without any problems by JPA provider (Hibernate). No additional mapping required here, as it is native SQL query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using postgresql (already the stack is telling that), and likely Hibernate, and almost certainly hitting this problem: [PostgreSQL JDBC Null String taken as a bytea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211195/postgresql-jdbc-null-string-taken-as-a-bytea)

I used this particular solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23501509/516188

So that means escaping to the Hibernate API so you can give the type of the expression.

In my case it was a nullable Short so I used:

`.setParameter("short", shortValue, ShortType.INSTANCE);`

shortValue being of type `Short`.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setParameter(java.lang.String, java.lang.Long, org.hibernate.type.LongType)'

Comment: Works with dates too -> ..setParameter("date", date, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 19):

I have faced the same issue when use `EntityManager.createNamedQuery`(guess the same issue with createNativeQuery).

In case you are going to pass `nullable` parameter to Query then use TypedParameterValue which allows to pass the type.

For instance:

```
setParameter("paramName", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, paramValue));
```

Here you explicitly set the type of passed value and when you pass null value as processor know the exact type.

Comment: Thanks. this helped me for Date field. 

`query.setParameter(6, new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.CALENDAR_DATE, null));`

Comment: This worked for me when the column type was Number

Answer (score 5):

if you are not using Hibernate, but you are using EclipseLink you can use the query Hint:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints

Example
query:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)";

em = getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
Query u = em.createNativeQuery(insert);
u.setHint(QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS, HintValues.FALSE);//<--the hint
u.setParameter(1, "value1");
u.setParameter(2, "value2");
u.setParameter(4, "value4");//just skipped the null element
u.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

and the result will be an insertion:

```
mytable
column1    column2    column3   column4
value1     value2               value4
```

of course if "column3" is nullable in the db...

I don't know if works also with Hibernate, but it could. I used PostgreSQL for my test.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using Oracle 12 and jboss 7.3, I solved using an empty String as param value. I don't understand why, but it works. This is my code:

```
String sql = "insert into customer (id,name,age) values (?1,?2,?3);
em = getEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, getId());
query.setParameter(2, getName());
if (getAge() != null) {//getAge() return BigDecimal and map a NUMBER column type
    query.setParameter(3, getAge());
} else {
   query.setParameter(3, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Double nullable parameter when using javax.persistence.Query native query against Postgresql

The simplest solution I found:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("insert into table_name (value_one, value_two, value_three) values (?,?,? ::decimal)");
q.setParameter(1, value1);
q.setParameter(2, value2);
q.setParameter(3, value3);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Note the type casting inside *insert* statement.

Alternative option:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("insert into table_name (value_one, value_two, value_three) values (?,?,cast(cast(? as text) as decimal))");
q.setParameter(1, value1);
q.setParameter(2, value2);
q.setParameter(3, value3);
q.executeUpdate();
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321877/13108438