# Cant set a date to null again

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, date

I am trying to set a previously set date field to null in oracle using hibernate but once the "nullable" column is set to a date, I can't set it to null again because I don't know how to represent the null date to pass as a parameter in the below query.

```
Query updateQuery;
updateQuery = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE STATION SET MOD_DT = ?1 WHERE STATION_ID = ?2");
updateQuery.setParameter(2, stationId);
updateQuery.setParameter(1, null);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Log:

```
g! Dec 02, 2014 4:41:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
<02-Dec-2014 16:41:46 o'clock EET> <Warning>   <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000>
Dec 02, 2014 4:41:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY

<02-Dec-2014 16:41:46 o'clock EET> <Error> <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query updateQuery;
updateQuery = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE STATION SET MOD_DT = null WHERE STATION_ID = ?1");
updateQuery.setParameter(1, stationId);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Some info here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9165

Answer (score 0):

try solution from this question:
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750785/817832)

setParameter with 3 arguments, one of argument is type of value