# Postgresql timestamp update set null

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a problem with timestamp field in postgresql database its

```
scheduled_time timestamp without time zone,
```

And i would like to get posibility to set it to null on update. But its still

> ERROR: column "scheduled_time" is of type timestamp without time zone
>   but expression is of type bytea   Wskazówka: You will need to rewrite
>   or cast the expression.

I tried to set it null, i tried to set it empty string "" i tried to find solutions at internet, i know that its work when i set it at pgadmin to null, but when i set as a parameter in

```
 queryString = "UPDATE upload SET additional_info=:additionalInfo, customer_id=:customerId, scheduled_time=:scheduledTime WHERE upload_id=:uploadId"; 
        final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);   
        query.setParameter("scheduledTime", upload.getScheduledTime());
        more setParameters ....
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Its still get me that message with type bytea. Can you tell me how to solve that?

I will do it by checking if scheduled is null. When true, i will make

```
UPDATE upload SET additional_info=:additionalInfo, customer_id=:customerId, scheduled_time= NULL WHERE upload_id=:uploadId
```

else i will

```
UPDATE upload SET additional_info=:additionalInfo, customer_id=:customerId, scheduled_time=:scheduledTime WHERE upload_id=:uploadId
```

couse i didn't find any normal solution.

Comment: What does `upload.getScheduledTime()` return?

Comment: i tried empty string, and null . I guess its set on query "null", but it should set null .

Comment: what kind of value does  upload.getScheduledTime() return if its "null"?   you will need to use an "if" condition to pass null value  query.setParameter("scheduledTime",null)

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/c645f0f6aed687a22f1627f7c2ba6324.png i tried to set it as , null ) its still not working. https://i.gyazo.com/e4da005bfe9e991656d33f31f482086f.png

Comment: What is the date format `upload.getScheduledTime()` return?

Comment: Have you tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731343/jpa-native-query-set-null-parameter ?

Comment: did you try  setnull(...) ?

Comment: This is not "plain" JDBC (e.g. `:additionalInfo` is an invalid parameter in JDBC). What kind of framework are you using to run this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this looks a lot like JPA (e.g. `entityManager`)