# NamedQuery with parameter null

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I have this namedQuery :

```
"SELECT new net.yy.domain.RemoteObject(r.id, r.name) 
FROM RemoteObject r LEFT JOIN r.tenant t
WHERE ((upper(r.name) like upper(:name) AND :name IS NOT NULL) OR :name IS NULL) 
AND ((upper(t.name) = upper(:tenant) AND :tenant IS NOT NULL) OR :tenant IS NULL)"
```

I call this with name or tenant in input.
With Oracle and mySQL, all is OK.
But with postgreSQL, the part "OR XX is null" seems to be ignored.
I have the error message :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function upper(bytea) does not exist
```

Have you an idea please ? The HQL request must be able to work with Oracle, Mysql and PostgreSQL.

The java class:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_ro_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_ro_gen", sequenceName = "SEQ_RO", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 64, unique = true)
private String name;

@Basic
@Column(name = "LOWERNAME", length = 64, unique = true)
private String lowerName;

@Basic
@Column(name = "PK", columnDefinition = "BLOB")
private byte[] pk;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TENANTID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Tenant tenant;

... Some other fields ...
```

And I override (only some fields)  with a specific postgresql file :

```
<entity class="RemoteObject">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="pk">
            <column name="PK" column-definition="text" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="NAME" column-definition="varchar" length="64" unique ="true" />
        </basic>
        <basic name="lowerName">
            <column name="LOWERNAME" column-definition="varchar" length="64" unique ="true" />
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Comment: Upper on a byte array makes no sense. Why are you storing names as byte arrays?

Comment: I don't use byte arrays ! Error is strange. name and tenant in input are String. (But String can be null).

Comment: Yes you do: "*function upper(bytea) does not exist* - `bytea` is a "byte array" - one of your columns (or parameters) is defined as `bytea` rather then `text` or `varchar`

Comment: Show the rest of the code. What is the content of `tenant` and `name`? How is mapped the RemoteObject?

Comment: I edited my post with details. The problem appears when one input (or both) is null. If both are not null, no error.

Comment: You need to show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements, not the Java code.

Comment: \d TABLE_REMOTEOBJECT :

id bigint //
lowername character varying // 
name character varying //
pk text // 
tenantid bigint

Comment: It seem's to be the same problem than here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211195/postgresql-jdbc-null-string-taken-as-a-bytea

Comment: What are you passing to `:tenant`? Post the code of `Tenant` entity too.