# Compare date if not null

Tags: java, postgresql

I need to find all the record with create date > X. X is a sql.Timestamp and might be null, in which case I want to just return all the records. So I tried: (createdAfter is Timestamp)

```
SELECT *
FROM sample AS s
WHERE s.isActive
  AND (:createdAfter ISNULL OR s.insert_time > :createdAfter)
```

But all I'm getting is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

However, if I'll do the same query where I'm checking for an arbitrary int to be null:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trades 
WHERE (:sInt ISNULL OR trades.insert_time > :createdAfter )
```

Then it works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution if you want to stick with native queries like that. The `null` value is converted to a `bytea` value. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8211195/6413377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21731343/6413377).

That value is quite hard to be casted or compared to a `timestamp` value.

The problem is not so much with the first comparison it would be handled by using coalesce, like:

```
COALESCE(:createdAfter) ISNULL
```

because there is no comparison beteween actual values and the data type does not matter. But the comparison

`sometimestamp::timestamp > null::bytea` (casts just to show the actual types so not working)

would need more logic behind maybe procedure & exception handling or so, not sure.

So if JPQL or CriteriaQueries are not possible for you have only bad options:

- contruct the query by setting params by string concatenation or so (NOT! and not sure if realy works)
- use `PreparedStatement` queries, more code & effort
- also if using Hibernate,  using session api like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23501509/6413377)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `pg_typeof` function, which returns a text string, and using a `CASE` statement to force which comparisons are made (otherwise there's no guarantee that postgres will short-circuit the OR in the correct order). You can then force the correct conversion by converting to text and then back to timestamp, which is inelegant but should be effective.

```
SELECT *
FROM sample AS s
WHERE s.isActive
  AND 
    CASE WHEN pg_typeof( :createdAfter ) = 'bytea' THEN TRUE
       WHEN s.insert_time > ( ( :createdAfter )::text)::timestamp THEN TRUE
       ELSE FALSE 
    END
```